# Add more criterion to SUMIFS

Tags: excel

```
=SUMIFS(Order1!C:C,Order1!B:B,A2,Order1!A:A,$Q$3)
```

How do I add multiple criteria to the second half of this `SUMIFS`?

Instead of only summing if `Q3` is found, it would also sum if `Q4` is found.

Comment: see https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic
and 
https://excelchamps.com/formulas/sumif-sumifs-or-logic/

Comment: To learn how to use a feature you're unfamiliar with, the best place to begin is the official documentation: https://www.google.com/search?q="sumifs"+site:microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

In Excel (Office 365) pass the multiple criteria in as a range (array).

The **SUMIFS** function will then be treated as an array formula and the results will be returned as an array, spilling across multiple cells.

To get the result into a single cell, wrap the **SUMIFS** formula in a **SUM** function.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5,$A$2:$A$5,$B$8:$B$9))
```

[image]